# Managing git repositories with another repository

Tags: git

Linux has lots of git repositories for different modules as listed [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/). There are also repositories for [developers](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/). But how does Linus merge all of these repositories and make a single kernel repository like [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/)? For instance, does he mark as submodule all of the related repositories or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git` thinks the opposite way: instead of generating a "master" repository, one generates "children" repositories called `submodules`.

Say that you have two `git` repositories that are located at:

```
foo.bar/baz
quix.qu/foobar
```

Then you can initialize a parent git repository (for instance in `parent`):

```
git init .
```

and add submodules:

```
git submodule add foo.bar/baz
git submodule add quix.qu/foobar
```

It will create the `baz` and `foobar` directory and initialize the appropriate git repositories there. The resulting `tree` is thus something like:

```
parent
├── baz
│   ├── content of baz
│   └── other content of baz
└── foobar
```

Submodules are thus what are links (shortcuts) in a non-versioning file system. They are useful if a part of a project tend "to go its own way" and commits are no longer global but you want commits to only capture for instance the `plugins` directory.

Comment: So Linus does this way, right? Using submodules I mean.

Comment: Think twice before introducing submodules in your git environment.